# File Location After Parse.com Migration to mongoDB

Tags: ios, mongodb, parse-platform

Where are my files after a Parse.com migration?  I have about 40 images stored in a directory file on Parse.com.  When I look at my mongoDb, it shows only about 578kb of data, so apparently, it's not storing the files there.  When I look at the data, I see this:

```
 "Picture": "tfss-ec79c5b8-f310-4256-8425-199edfc67bfd-Rawlins.JPG"
}
```

Does that mean that everything is still stored on Parse, and once 1/28/17 hits I will lose the image, or does mongoDb have it just really compressed.  If it is still on Parse.com, how do I get the image moved over to mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this link:

https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-files-utils
it helped me, hope it will help you too.

can you follow this steps first:
[image]

Comment: I had seen this just after I posted my question.  Is this something that can still be used, despite the fact that I've already migrated my data (can only be done once, apparently), and only need pictures transferred to S3?

Comment: That is fine if you have already migrated your data, transferring pictures to S3 is a separate thing you can do it now.

Comment: I have already migrated data, but for the life of me, I don't understand how to now move images

Comment: That doesn't work.  I get this error message `Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
`

Comment: Use git clone https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-files-utils.git

Comment: Ok, I did this, and it renamed the files in the mongoDB as expected, but uploaded nothing to S3.  The bucket I created in AWS is still empty.